# missing bitcoin

Tags: blockchain

I bought some bitcoin from an bitcoin machine,but they never arrived the machine did  give me a receipt of address which I did take the picture of can anybody tell me what happened and what I need to do?

Comment: Yes, we can to the first part of your question, but we need the address to do that. What you need to do is contact support. Give them plenty of details, like amount, location and datetime of withdrawal.

Answer (score 1):

No one can know what happened if you didn't receive the bitcoin
Contact the support